# How to write zsh completion function for wrapper commands

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete

I'm attempting to write a completion function for a custom wrapper around SSH called myssh. myssh takes command line arguments in either of the following forms:

```
myssh [myssh options] [ssh args]
```

or

```
myssh [myssh options] -- [ssh options] [ssh args]
```

How can I provide completion for myssh-specific options while reusing existing completion for ssh?

edit: I'd also like to use the `_gnu_generic` function [mentioned here](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org#completing-generic-gnu-commands) for completing myssh options.

Comment: For people who don’t have `myssh options`, they can simply `compdef myssh=ssh`. Hope this helps future visitors from Google.

Answer (score 0):

In a more general case where @Franklin\ Yu's comment does not suffice you can make a corresponding completion command. Take for example the `flux` command. This command, and many like it, is rather picky and expects its first parameter to the completion command to be the original command's name, so this fails:

```
$ compdef myflux=flux
$ myflux<tab>
l2advertisement.yaml  pool.yaml # <--- not expected
```

Introducing a helper command which replaces the first `myflux` in the `$words` variable fixes this:

```bash
_myflux() {
  words="flux ${words[@]:1}"     # replace myflux with flux, in `words` array
  _flux                           # call original completion command which expects a words array beginning with `flux`
}

$ compdef _myflux myflux

$ myflux<tab> 
bootstrap   -- Deploy Flux on a cluster the GitOps way.
build       -- Build a flux resource
check ...
...
# the above *is* expected.
```

Sometimes you are wrapping an original command with subcommands, like `flux get source`

The line with the mutation of the `$words` array would then become:

```bash
  words="flux get source ${words[@]:1}"
```